# Fetch retrieves a serialized object from the server. Why is it already deserialized when examined inside the fetch?

Tags: node.js, express, fetch-api

Using the fetch api, the node.js server sends back the following serialized object:

```
app.get('/getJoe', function(request, response) {

      var myObj = {};
      myObj.firstname = "Joe";
      myObj.age = 23;
      var myObjSerialized = JSON.stringify(myObj);
      response.send(myObjSerialized); //sends {"firstname":"Joe","age":23}

});
```

The fetch API processes the response as follows:

```
function getJoe(){

    fetch('/getJoe')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((person) => {
      console.log(typeof(person)); //outputs object
      console.log(person) //outputs {firstname: "Joe", age: 23}
    })
}
```

Why isn't fetch rendering the stringified object the same way it is rendered on the server?

Put another way, if the server responds to a fetch request with the following stringified object:

{"firstname":"Joe","age":23}

Shouldn't the fetch still see it as stringified?  Why instead does it render it as:

{firstname: "Joe", age: 23}

Moreover, instead of having to convert person back into an object (using JSON.parse(person) ) person can already be treated as an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
return response.json();
```

line takes in the `Response` stream and returns a `Promise` that resolves to a *deserialized* version of the response. If you wanted only the plain text, you would use the `.text()` method instead:

```
return response.text();
```

This automatic deserialization is particular to `fetch` and `fetch`'s `.json()` method. If you were to use `XMLHttpRequest`, you *would* have only a text response, which you would have to transform back into an object using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: What I found interesting is that deserialization can occur on any valid JSON *value* (according to MDN), can you confirm this?

Comment: Sure, I imagine it invokes `JSON.parse`, which can indeed parse any valid JSON

Comment: I imagined that too and confirmed with `JSON.parse('[{"a":8}]')` and `JSON.parse('8.8')`. Oddly enough, I never knew JSON could be anything other than an object at the root level :\ (despite stating that clearly on its homepage)

Comment: Thanks for those responses.  It clarifies this quite a bit.  Revisiting the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json seems to confirm what you say; that the json() method invokes JSON.parse.  Still, I think that could have been said more explicitly in the doc.  For me anyway it wasn't the expected behavior.